# how to keep your model scale from an animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

I was animating a model and noticed that on a frame that the scale there looked a lot better then the current scale my model has by default. What I would like to know is how to I apply the scale of the model in that frame so that it's now the model's permanent scale if that makes sense?

This is the default model scale:

[![Model and character design are property of CraftyMaelyss][1]][1]

And this is the scale I want my model to be:

[![Model and character design are property of CraftyMaelyss][2]][2]

I read somewhere that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> should do it, so I tried it and it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Upload your model to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so other may try with your file.

Comment: If I get your question right, you were animating the model INCLUDING the scale channels, right? If that's the case, all you got to do is go to the specific frame where you like the scale values, and in the transform panel right click and choose 'Clear Keyframes'

Comment: @aliasguru, you should post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Choose the object (not the armature), go to the frame you want it to be and apply the armature modifier.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work when I changed the window from animation to default or changed from pose mode to object or edit mode :/

Comment: I have not understand from the question that the object is manipulated with armature. See the answer now - it was modified.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I tried that and I tried it again just then to test it and it still didn't work :(

Comment: You said you applied "cntrlA". I say you go to modifiers and apply the armature modifier of the mesh.

Comment: It's still not working :( I'll just maybe start from scratch and try again since nothing seems to help :(

Comment: Its a pitty to make all from scratch. Select the mesh in question. It had a modifier, right? Armature modifier, right? Go to the frame you want. Make it a new keyframe. Go to modifier and apply it. Delete all the other keyframes. Look what hapens. You have some animated patents attached to this mesh?

Comment: -1; sorry for downvoting, but this isn't needed and will make it **impossible to pose** the character.